# Uncommon notations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I'm reading [a paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=10110974) on Federated Learning with non-iid data and I'm having a hard time understanding several equations they present. I have a feeling that their notation is not rigorous but I'd love to have a second opinion. As an example does this statement (p.42084 ) makes sense?

> Note that i is a higher set than j; ∃i⊃∀j since j is an index of data
> on local i

Comment: The expression   ∃i⊃∀j is not well-formed as standard mathematical notation.  Presumably it has some meaning in this particular context.

Comment: I can't make sense of it. But, I don't think I should expect to. Maybe asking someone on a Comp Sci forum would make more sense? Whatever notation they are using, is distinct from what is standard for Mathematicians.

Comment: Thanks, I can move the thread indeed. I come from a computer science background and this doesn't make any sense to me. This is why I thought of asking here.